# object reference not set to an instance of an object in "team foundation server" 2012

Tags: c#-4.0, tfs

I am very new to Microsoft Team Foundation Server.  I am trying to add a Team Project to an existing Collection.

I did File--> New --> Team Project

The dialog box comes up, I type in the name of the Team Project and click Next
I selected the Scrum 2.0 selection (default) clicked next 
clicked next again
then finish.

I get:  "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Has anyone come across this before?  I have permissions as an Admin in the TFS Server.

Thank you all!

Dave

Comment: Is this the only error information you get? I would expect that there is something wrong with the Process Template. Did you try to create a project with another template?

Comment: I solved my own problem.  I was logged into TFS from 4 different locations --> (see my avatar).

Answer (score 2):

I was logged into TFS from 4 different locations accidentally.  When my administrator logged me off of those, it fixed my problem.

The error really through me for a loop because it was pretty odd for what the problem was.